# Wrapping and itemizing in a table which already allows text wrap

Tags: tables, tabularx, tabulary

Packages loaded and code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage{array,ltablex, makecell}%
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
% \renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\leftmargin$#1$}%This is for descriptions to appear on the LHS with an indent
\newenvironment{conditions}
 {\par\vspace{\abovedisplayskip}\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{${}={}$} l}}
 {\end{tabular}\par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}}%This is for descriptions of equations
\usepackage[]{multirow}%Essential for cells in table spanning multiple rows
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}% This is for quotes
\usepackage{tabulary}% This is for tables
\usepackage{longtable,array,ragged2e}% This is formatting for long tables
\usepackage{tabularx,caption}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>
{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}%This is a wrapper to make everything a certain width -left aligned columns with stuff at the top.
\newcolumntype{U}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%This is a wrapper to make everything a certain width -left aligned columns with stuff at the top.
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned.
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}%C is for central aligned columns and middle aligned.
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
% \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}%This is to force new lines in cells
\usepackage{graphicx}% This is for images
\usepackage{booktabs,dcolumn,caption}
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{#1}}%This is for precision tables per property
%

\begin{table}[!ht]
 \small
 \caption{Freebase Relation Example}
 \centering
\begin{tabular}{|p{3.25cm}|p{3.25cm}|}
\toprule
\textbf{Entity-Pair} & \textbf{<Barack Obama, US>} \\
\midrule
\multirow{2}{*}{Relation instances from knowledge bases} & 
1. \textbf{PresidentOf(Barack Obama, US)} \\ &
2. \textbf{BornIn(Barack Obama, US)} \\
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Relation mentions from free texts} & 1. \textbf{Barack Obama} is the 44th and current president of the \textbf{US} (PresidentOf) \\ &
2. \textbf{Barack Obama} ended \textbf{US} military involvement in the Iraq War. (*) \\ & 
3. \textbf{Barack Obama} was born in Honolulu, Hawaii, \textbf{US}. (BornIn) \\ &
4. \textbf{Barack Obama} ran for the \textbf{US} senate in 2004. (SenateOf) \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

I am trying to recreate:

[image]

However a) I cannot do an `itemize` within this `tabular` environment and b) the first column doesn't wrap my text to the fixed 3.25cm width I give it.

Current table:

[image]

Comment: Please see my answer and the comments to your other question first. It makes no sense to define the column types as you do; it makes no sense to use `tabularx` if you want to set the widths of all columns; you shouldn't be overwriting `tabulary`'s definitions, if you load it. You code cannot possibly compile as posted. You need to include code for your class. You need a `document` environment. In addition, you really do not want to combine vertical rules with `booktabs` rules. However, note that, as `booktabs` explains, if you want high quality tables, don't use vertical rules.

Comment: I see you are asking lots of questions about tables. You seem to be trying to do some advanced stuff, while not really unserstanding the basics. Most tables don't need to be advanced at all, so just stick to basic stuff. They will probably look a lot better, and more consistant, since it is easier to maintain.

Comment: I'm not doing advanced stuff, I'm trying to do stuff that has been done - that table. I would say text wrap in a table is pretty basic.

Comment: is this problem solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!ht]
  \setenumerate{noitemsep}% Removes spaces between items in list.
  \rowcolors{2}{white}{yellow!10}% This will color every even row. use \rowcolor{color} if you only want to color a single row.
  \small
  \caption{Freebase Relation Example}
  \centering
  \renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}% To have tabularx use the m-columntype instead of p, so that we can center the content virtically
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{>{\centering}m{3.25cm}X}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Entity-Pair} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{\textless Barack Obama, US\textgreater}} \\
    \midrule
      Relation instances

      from

      knowledge bases &%
      % \vspace*{-\topsep}\vspace*{-\parsep}%
      \begin{enumerate}
        \item \textbf{PresidentOf(Barack Obama, US)}
        \item \textbf{PresidentOf(Barack Obama, US)}
      \end{enumerate}\\
      \midrule
      Relation mentions

      from

      free texts &
      % \vspace*{-\topsep}\vspace*{-\parsep}%To remove space from top of enumerate
      \begin{enumerate}
          \item \textbf{Barack Obama} is the 44th and current president of the \textbf{US} (President of)
          \item \textbf{Barack Obama} ended \textbf{US} military involvement in the Iraq War. (-)
          \item \textbf{Barack Obama} was born in Honolulu, Hawaii, \textbf{US}. (Born in)
          \item \textbf{Barack Obama} ran for the \textbf{US} senate in 2004. (Senate of)
        \end{enumerate}\\
      \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I ran this and am getting: `./Chapters/Background.tex:340:
LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missin
g \item.` just at `\end{tabularx}`. I shifted my packages to load in the order you have, only I load `ltablex` instead of `tabularx`

Comment: Solved by changing to `tabular`.

Answer (score 0):

While you can specify an environment (`\center`, `\raggedright`) in `\newcolumntype`, you may also specify a cell-specific environment with `minipage`. You can then insert an image, a list or even a subtable in it!

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lllll}
\toprule
ColA & ColB & ColC & ColD & ColE \\ 
\midrule
Left (year) & Left & Left & \begin{minipage}[b]{0.10\textwidth}\raggedleft
Right 
\end{minipage} & Left \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example Table with cell-specific minipage environment]

Comment: (+1) Yes, `minipage` is a good way. However, I recommend you to make an a-bit-more-complicated table (i.e., add a minimal list, etc.) because only a right-aligned "Right" doesn't tell much.